# How to create a Python package so that modules can be updated independently

Tags: python, module, package, packaging

I am writing a Python package `collection` that is a collection of packages and modules.

For example in `collection` I have a package called `misc` which contains a module `experimental` and a module `os`, and a package `data` that has some modules `read` and `write`.

It is still in development, but when I have a stable code, I would like to upload it on PyPI.

I would like to know how I can organize my code so that each package in `collection` can have its own version number. The main purpose is that I would like to be able to upgrade the modules independently: say that I modify `misc`, but not `data` I would like that `collection.misc` can be upgraded without having to download `data` as well (or all the other packages), when upgrading with 
`pip install -U collection`.

Ideally I would like to organize the code so that each package can be developed independently, while still being part of collection.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `seed`. It is a utility for easily creating and releasing Python packages.
http://seed.readthedocs.org/en/latest/